# How to get GL library and header for windows 7?

Tags: c++, opengl, window

I have to port a Linux OpenGL program to Windows. That program has to be integrated to a qt program. The program uses GLUI, GLU and GLUT libraries. I manage to download glut libraries but it is not having GLUI, GLU and other specific libraries. Where I can download GLUI, GLU libraries and header files for Windows? I don't have Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2):

GLUI is a third party library, you can find it on [sourceforge](http://glui.sourceforge.net/).

GLUT is another third party library, more info on [opengl.org](https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/).

The glu header is part of the windows platform sdk. If you have a working C++ compiler toolchain for windows (can be visual studio or mingw), it should be in it.

Comment: thanks for the reply. i can download only source code of glui but not direct libraries. so only way i have to build and use ?

Comment: Yes, you have to build it.

Comment: ok . i will build and get the lib and include files. thank you